# Symbol not found

Tags: java, web-applications, compiler-errors, package, symbol-not-found

**DBHelper.java**

```
package com.control;    
import java.sql.*;    
public class DBHelper 
{
Connection conn;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
public DBHelper()throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
}

public boolean getConnection()throws SQLException
{
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");
    if(conn!=null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void execute(String query)throws SQLException
{
    st=conn.createStatement();
    st.execute(query);

}
public boolean match(String uname,String pwd)throws Exception
{
    st=conn.createStatement();
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from register");


        while(rs.next())
        {
            String unm=rs.getString(1);
            String pd=rs.getString(2);
            if(uname.equals(unm) && pwd.equals(pd))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;


}



}
```

**LoginSevlet.java**

```
package com.control;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet
{


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        try{
        DBHelper obj=new DBHelper();
        obj.getConnection();
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        String uname=req.getParameter("email");
        String pwd=req.getParameter("password");
        //ResultSet rs=obj.match(uname,pwd);
        //if(uname.equals(rs.getString(1)) && pwd.equals(rs.getString(2)))
        if(obj.match(uname,pwd))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("profile.html");
            rd.forward(req,res);

        }
        else
        {

            RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
            rd.include(req,res);
            out.println("<b>Incorrect Email or password!</b>");
        }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    }    
}
```

> I am trying to access DBHelper class in LoginServlet while Compilation i did *javac DBHelper.java*
>   javac -cp "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\MYServlet\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;" LoginServlet.java
>   LoginServlet.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>                          DBHelper obj=new DBHelper();
>                          ^
>    symbol:   class DBHelper
>    location: class LoginServlet
>   LoginServlet.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>                  DBHelper obj=new DBHelper();
>                                           ^
>    symbol:   class DBHelper
>    location: class LoginServlet
>   2 errors
>   I have placed .java files in C:\Users\dell\Desktop\MYServlet\WEB-INF\classes\com\control
>   All the Files are in the same package and that too public then why cant LoginServlet access DBHelper class

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not `import com.control.*;` in your class `LoginServlet`.
More on packages [Java packages](http://www.javatpoint.com/package)
and please try to use right commands to compile and execute while using packages.

Comment: They are within same package then why should i import and i think the keyword package in your import statement is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for that,Updated.

Comment: i even tried importing but it ends up with same error

Comment: You need to import your package here.try it

Comment: Okay,can you please tell how you compiling and executing your classes.?

Comment: i have mentioned in post steps of compilation and errors too.

Comment: No,that is not a correct way to compile classes when you use packages.

Comment: Please refer to that mentioned above link.

Comment: you will get clear understanding how to deal with packages

Comment: if i do javac -d . DBHelper.java  it creates com/control/DBHelper inside control folder and  javac -cp "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\MYServlet\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;" LoginServlet.java how  can i specify -d ?

Comment: if you want to directly put your .class file in WEB-INF/classes folder,use this "javac -d C:/Users/dell/Desktop/MYServlet\WEB-INF/classes DBHelper.java

Comment: But still LoginServlet is unable to find my class still the same error

Comment: Can anyone answer to this post?